# Printing header for PL SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, procedure, stored-functions

I have the following SQL Procedure code:

```
create or replace procedure numOfSupplier(X IN NUMBER)IS
OUTPUT VARCHAR(500);

BEGIN 

    FOR supplerTable IN (SELECT R_NAME, N_NAME
    FROM SUPPLIER join NATION on S_NATIONKEY = N_NATIONKEY
    join REGION on N_REGIONKEY = R_REGIONKEY
    GROUP BY R_NAME, N_NAME
    HAVING COUNT (S_NATIONKEY) > X)

LOOP

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (supplerTable.R_NAME || supplerTable.N_NAME);

END LOOP;

END numOfSupplier;
/
```

When ran, gives me: https://i.imgur.com/zEEKpya.png

I'm trying to have this show: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLXPF.png

Any idea how to print the header out?

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE seems limited

Thanks in advance!

PS, I tried having a DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE before the loop but it errored out:

12/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" when expecting
     one of the following:
     loop
     The symbol "loop" was substituted for "DBMS_OUTPUT" to continue.

20/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMOFSUPPLIER" when expecting
     one of the following:
     loop

Error when trying:

```
OUTPUT VARCHAR(500);

BEGIN 

    FOR supplerTable IN (SELECT R_NAME, N_NAME
    FROM SUPPLIER join NATION on S_NATIONKEY = N_NATIONKEY
    join REGION on N_REGIONKEY = R_REGIONKEY
    GROUP BY R_NAME, N_NAME
    HAVING COUNT (S_NATIONKEY) > X)

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('HELLO');

LOOP

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (supplerTable.R_NAME || supplerTable.N_NAME);

END LOOP;

END numOfSupplier;
/
```

Comment: Why don't you use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` before the loop to print a header?

Comment: I tried, errored out, but it seems you can only have 1 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE per procedure?  ----------- 12/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DBMS_OUTPUT" when expecting
  one of the following:
  loop
  The symbol "loop" was substituted for "DBMS_OUTPUT" to continue.
/////////
20/5  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMOFSUPPLIER" when expecting
  one of the following:
  loop

Comment: "but it seems you can only have 1 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE" -- No. You must have made a mistake. Probably show the code where you tried that.

Comment: I've updated the original post, thanks so much for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in the middle of the loop's header. You have to put it completely before the loop.

```
...
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('<The header goes here>');

FOR supplerTable IN (...) LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (supplerTable.R_NAME || supplerTable.N_NAME);
END LOOP;
...
```

Comment: I did! My DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('HELLO') is before the LOOP; - https://i.imgur.com/xarej0o.png this is returns error!

Comment: @CharlotteE: No you didn't. You put it before the `LOOP` keyword but that is not where a `FOR` loop begins. It begins with the `FOR` keyword. Have you even tried my suggestion?

Comment: @CharlotteE: See my edit. Maybe that makes it clearer where to put it. Also note that you possibly have a typo, `supplerTable` should probably be `supploerTable`. But that has nothing to do with the other problem.

Comment: Yeah! So sorry to trouble you, just started learning PL Procedures/Functions so the previous one wasn't clear! Thanks for your help, stay safe